# Ejecutar funcion segun el estado de un checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas gente, resulta que tengo un tema, estoy haciendo una interface para controlar una arduino que tengo, y lo que hice fue con JavaScript enviar una peticion GET cuando se presiona el boton encender y otra al presionar el boton apagar, lo que quiero es usar un `checkbox` y que al seleccionarlo se ejecute la funcion `on()` y al des seleccionarlo la funcion `off()`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function on2() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var url = "http://192.168.0.104/r2=ON";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  var respo= xmlhttp.responseText;
  
 }

 function off2() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var url = "http://192.168.0.104/r2=OFF";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  var respo= xmlhttp.responseText;
  
 }
</script>
```

Comment: <button onclick='on2()'>Encender</button>
<button onclick='off2()'>Apagar</button>

Simple, lo que quiero es que sea 1 solo checkbox y al cambiar de estado ejecute la funcion on() o off()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes realizar una condición comprobando si el checkbox está en true o en false con el atributo `checked` del checkbox.

Luego le puedes asignar un evento al checkbox para que se ejecute cuando ha cambiado su estado mediante la función `addEventListener` e indicándole que se ejecute con el evento `change`.

Ejemplo:

```js
function on(){
  console.log("Hemos pulsado en on");
}

function off(){
  console.log("Hemos pulsado en off");
}

var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", comprueba, false);

function comprueba(){
  if(checkbox.checked){
      on();
  }else{
     off();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
var checkBox = document.querySelector('#iddetucheckbox');
checkBox.addEventListener('change', verificarEstado, false);

function verificarEstado(e) {
    if(e.target.checked){
        on();
    }else{
        off();
    }
}
```